# Custom UITableView cell image transform not applied to reusable cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell that displays a circular image on the left-hand side. Since the default UIImageView supplied with the UITableViewCell is the same height as the row, the images end up nearly touching. I'd like to shrink the image slightly to create some extra padding.

I was able to get this to work using the following code

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    // Make the image view slightly smaller than the row height
    self.imageView!.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)

    // Round corners
    self.imageView!.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView!.bounds.height / 2.0
    self.imageView!.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    self.imageView!.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    self.imageView!.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.imageView!.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill;

    self.updateConstraints()
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.imageView!.image = nil
    self.layoutSubviews()
}
```

This works only for the cells displayed in the table view when it first appears on the screen. Once I scroll (i.e. dequeue a re-usable cell),  the transform is no longer applied. The image below shows the left side of the table view. I've captured the region where the original cells transition to re-used cells.

[image]

For completeness, here is my tableView(cellForRowAt:) function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.itemTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell") as! InventoryItemTableViewCell

    if let items = self.displayedItems {
        if indexPath.row < items.count {
            let item = items[indexPath.row]

            cell.item = item
            cell.textLabel!.text = items[indexPath.row].partNumber
            cell.detailTextLabel!.text = items[indexPath.row].description

            if let quantity = items[indexPath.row].quantity {
                cell.quantityLabel.text = "Qty: \(Int(quantity))"
            }
            else {
                cell.quantityLabel.text = "Qty: N/A"
            }

            if let stringImageBase64 = item.imageBase64 {
                let dataDecoded: Data = Data(base64Encoded: stringImageBase64, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
                cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(data: dataDecoded)
            }
            else {
                cell.imageView!.image = blankImage
            }
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

I tried other methods such as playing with the image view's insets but this had no effect.

**Question**

Why is the transform being applied to the original cells when the table is created but not to any re-used cells? Should I be approaching this differently?

Comment: Is layoutSubviews called when cell is reused?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish resizing the image using the following code. It seems the autolayout is applied after the transform, therefore overriding it.

```
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        // Layout all subviews except for the image view
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // Make the image view slightly smaller than the row height
        self.imageView!.frame = CGRect(x: self.imageView!.frame.origin.x + 4,
                                       y: self.imageView!.frame.origin.y + 4,
                                       width: 56,
                                       height: 56)

        // Round corners
        self.imageView!.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView!.frame.height / 2.0
        self.imageView!.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        self.imageView!.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        self.imageView!.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.imageView!.clipsToBounds = true
        self.imageView!.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit;
    }
```